# Using SharePoint Contacts with Outlook

Tags: outlook, contacts

A client has asked if they can use SharePoint as a central contacts repository. I have created a list of test contacts in SharePoint, and successfully used "Connect to Outlook", which adds the SharePoint contacts to Outlook as an additional contacts folder.

I need the same thing to happen in OWA, and also Outlook for iPhone but it but so far have no luck.  I've installed Microsoft's SharePoint Mobile App on the iPhone, but can't see a way to make it sync SharePoint contacts.